# Swap two curves in the editor graph

Tags: animation, nla-editor, graph-editor

I am wondering if possible to swap two curves in editor graphs? or to modify a curve to be constant =0 (no motion)?

Comment: For the latter you can select the curve and then press `S` (scale) `Y` (y axis) `0`

Comment: Add limit modifier with MAX_Y and MIN_Y set to 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To switch two points on a graph select them and press <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>-</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>

And to scale to 0 (as pointed out by @gandalf3)  <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>Y</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd>
[image]