# Trying to get the right orientation matrix

Tags: python, armature, import, keyframes, matrix

So i'm using a importer that uses a matrix and changes the transform and when i try and import with my keyframe data the arms and legs are like backwards? Crossed not sure how to explain it. So i'm trying to see if i got the orientation right of this matrix. EDIT: This is coming from a 
[D3DXMATRIX](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d9/d3dxmatrix)

```
    correct_orientation = mathutils.Matrix([[1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], #left/right
                                        [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], #front/back
                                        [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0], #up/down
                                        [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0]]) #flip inside/out?
armature.transform(correct_orientation)
mesh.transform(correct_orientation)
```

[image]

Comment: Please consider adding more info, eg images of rest pose, a pose bone and its transforms _& what they "should" be_ ,.... as , It's hard to get a read on this from  information given. My guess is possibly require something like https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50101/swap-two-curves-in-the-graph-editor/50136#50136  since the axes have been changed. (and possible the sign for any axes axes that are inverted) .